# Wordpress, Apache and Nginx: permalinks and cache

Tags: apache, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

I have a server with **Ubuntu 14.04.1**, **Apache** at port `8008` and **nginx** at port `80` as a proxy for **Apache**. It runs a website based on **Wordpress**.

I use **Wordpress**'s plugin **WP Super Cache** with the following settings:

[image]

Also I use **Permalinks** like this:

[image]

When I had only **Apache** at port `80` (**nginx** was not installed back then), everything was working just fine.

But now (with **Apache** at `8008` and **nginx** at `80`) the problem is: I can load only title page, like `example.com`, and other links like `example.com/2015/05/16/somepost` don't load and return back to the title page `example.com`.

Here's the **nginx** website config (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite`):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www;
    index index.php;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
            deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            expires max;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8008;
    }
}
```

And that's `/var/www/.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried the following advices:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936618/500-error-with-nginx-and-wordpress-pretty-permalinks
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17282963/wordpress-nginx-preview-post-is-404-not-found-but-old-posts-are-working
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27593466/plesk-nginx-wordpress-permanent-links-404-not-found-nginx

But none of them helped.

By the way, `http://example.com/wp-admin/` works anytime, so I guess the trouble is related to cache (**WP Super Cache**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After ***a while*** researching and experimenting I've managed to find solution:

1. Install plugin [Permalink Fix & Disable Canonical Redirects Pack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/);
2. Change the `location /` block in my config (the one I posted above) like that:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```